# Is there an equivalent SQL query to SHOW WAREHOUSES;

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm looking for SQL code equivalent to SHOW but as a Select statement.

Available: SELECT DATABASE_NAME FROM "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."DATABASES"

Not Available???: SELECT WAREHOUSE_NAME FROM "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."WAREHOUSES"

Answer (score 2):

You could potentially make use of the [RESULT_SCAN](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/result_scan.html) function.

So you could first run:

```
SHOW WAREHOUSES;
```

And then run:

```
SELECT * FROM table(result_scan(last_query_id()));
```

If you're doing this programmatically, then keep track of the query ID and pass it into the function like so:

```
SELECT * FROM table(result_scan('ce6687a4-331b-4a57-a061-02b2b0f0c17c'));
```

Comment: I would like to create a view of SHOW WAREHOUSES for a Power BI dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You could use: 
SELECT DISTINCT WAREHOUSE_NAME FROM "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."WAREHOUSE_METERING_HISTORY" ORDER BY 1;

Comment: Yes, I started with that but the results returned include dropped/renamed virtual warehouses. I can't seem to find an active/deleted column limit those VWHs. The SHOW WAREHOUSES returns over 25 columns.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the last_query_id() method posted above and it worked.

We can extend that further by populating that data into a custom table and then creating a task to have this run on a regular basis, like below:

```
    USE WAREHOUSE <wh_name>;
    USE DATABASE <db_name>;
    USE SCHEMA <schema_name>;
    
    -- Create a stored proc:
    
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE <proc_name>() 
    RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL 
    LANGUAGE SQL 
    AS 
    BEGIN 
      SHOW WAREHOUSES;
      CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE <db_name>.<schema_name>.<table_name> AS SELECT * FROM 
    table(result_scan(last_query_id()));
      RETURN 'DONE';
    END;
    
    -- Create a task to execute the stored proc on a regular basis:
    
    CREATE TASK <task_name> 
      WAREHOUSE = <wh_name> 
      SCHEDULE = '480 MINUTE' 
    AS 
      call <db_name>.<schema_name>.<proc_name>()
    ;
    
    -- Check if the stored proc is working by executing below statements one by one:
    
    truncate table <db_name>.<schema_name>.<table_name>;
    
    select * from <db_name>.<schema_name>.<table_name>;
    
    call <db_name>.<schema_name>.<proc_name>();
    
    select * from <db_name>.<schema_name>.<table_name>;
    
    -- Check if the task is working by executing below statements one by one:
    
    truncate table <db_name>.<schema_name>.<table_name>;
    
    select * from <db_name>.<schema_name>.<table_name>;
    
    execute task <task_name>;
    
    -- Give a few seconds for the task to complete execution before executing below:
    select * from <db_name>.<schema_name>.<table_name>;
```